# Calculate number of slopes, number of value changes in SQL

Tags: sql, detection, clickhouse

I'm trying to make a code to calculate number of slopes, number of value changes and duration of each state in SQL

I've got table like the following:

```
    | Module   | MeasTime          | MeasDate  | Variable| Value|
    | ---      | ---               | ---       | ---     | ---  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 00:00:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 00:10:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 00:20:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 00:30:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 00:40:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 00:50:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 01:00:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   0  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 01:10:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   0  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 01:20:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   0  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 01:30:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   0  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 01:40:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 01:50:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 02:00:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 02:10:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 02:20:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 02:30:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 02:40:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   0  |
 
 .
 .
 .
```

Do you have an idea how i can do this in SQL in a good performing way ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bclickhouse%5DarraySplit

Answer (score 0):

I partialy solve a problem:

```
Number of values changes:
Select Module, Variable, Count(Diff)
FROM (
    SELECT Module, Variable, runningDifference(Value) as Diff
    FROM 'XX' 
    WHERE Diff = -1 or Diff = 1
)
GROUP BY Module, Variable
```

Hope, its a good way..and it works for my problem

But still have problem with state duration...